# Create a streaming example with Calcite using CSV

Tags: java, csv, stream, apache-calcite

I am trying to create a basic stream program with Calcite using CSV for data source.I can run queries with sqlline, but I can't do it programmatically. My code is:

example.json

```
{
  version: '1.0',
  defaultSchema: 'STREAM',
  schemas: [
    {
      name: 'SS',
      tables: [
        {
          name: 'ORDERS',
          type: 'custom',
          factory: 'org.apache.calcite.adapter.csv.CsvStreamTableFactory',
          stream: {
            stream: true
          },
          operand: {
            file: 'sales/SORDERS.csv',
            flavor: "scannable"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

SORDERS.csv

```
PRODUCTID:int,ORDERID:int,UNITS:int
3,4,5
2,5,12
2,1,6
```

SimpleQuery.java

```
package stream_test;

import org.apache.calcite.adapter.java.ReflectiveSchema;
import org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnection;
import org.apache.calcite.schema.SchemaPlus;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Example of using Calcite via JDBC.
 *
 * <p>Schema is specified programmatically.</p>
 */
public class SimpleQuery {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new SimpleQuery().run();
  }

  public void run() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver");
    Properties info = new Properties();
    info.setProperty("lex", "JAVA");
    Connection connection =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:model="
                + "/home/hduser/Downloads/calcite-master/example/csv/target/test-classes/example.json",info);
    CalciteConnection calciteConnection =
        connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
    //SchemaPlus rootSchema = calciteConnection.getRootSchema();
    //rootSchema.add("os", new ReflectiveSchema(new Os()));
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet =
            statement.executeQuery("select stream * from SS.ORDERS where SS.ORDERS.UNITS > 5");
    final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      int n = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        buf.append(i > 1 ? "; " : "")
            .append(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i))
            .append("=")
            .append(resultSet.getObject(i));
      }
      System.out.println(buf.toString());
      buf.setLength(0);
    }
    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
  }

}
```

Finally I have dependencies of calcite-core 1.8.0, net.sf.opencsv 2.3 , calcite-avatica 1.6.0, calcite-linq4j 1.8.0, sqlline 1.1.9, hamcrest-core 1.3, com.github.stephenc.jcip 1.0-1 , commons-lang3 3.4, guava 19.0
and imported calcite-example-csv-1.9.0-SNAPSHOT (which I packed with maven from the github version).

When I try to run the code I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CANCEL_FLAG
    at org.apache.calcite.adapter.csv.CsvStreamScannableTable.scan(CsvStreamScannableTable.java:66)
    at org.apache.calcite.interpreter.TableScanNode.createScannable(TableScanNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.calcite.interpreter.TableScanNode.create(TableScanNode.java:94)
    at org.apache.calcite.interpreter.Nodes$CoreCompiler.visit(Nodes.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.calcite.util.ReflectUtil.invokeVisitorInternal(ReflectUtil.java:257)
    at org.apache.calcite.util.ReflectUtil.invokeVisitor(ReflectUtil.java:214)
    at org.apache.calcite.util.ReflectUtil$1.invokeVisitor(ReflectUtil.java:471)
    at org.apache.calcite.interpreter.Interpreter$Compiler.visit(Interpreter.java:476)
    at org.apache.calcite.interpreter.Interpreter$Compiler.visitRoot(Interpreter.java:433)
    at org.apache.calcite.interpreter.Interpreter.<init>(Interpreter.java:75)
    at Baz.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalcitePrepare$CalciteSignature.enumerable(CalcitePrepare.java:327)
    at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.enumerable(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:282)
    at     package stream_test;
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse I used:

As maven dependencies:
commons-io 2.4 , commons-logging 1.1.3 , commons-lang3 3.2 , janino 2.7.6 , eigenbase-properties 1.1.5 , avatica 1.8.0, opencsv 2.3 , json-simple 1.1

and as external jars :
calcite-core 1.9.0, example-csv-1.9.0, calcite-linq4j 1.9.0  (all SNAPSHOT versions) after creating them with mvn install command from github latest version of calcite.

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched libraries (calcite-example-csv version 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT, versus calcite-core version 1.8.0). See [the discussion on calcite dev list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/calcite-dev/201609.mbox/%3CCACBy0-0C1wYkYHpydh-WZN4xfGyNLkMtXuA_HWeCrLPpg6SyTg%40mail.gmail.com%3E) for more details.

Comment: I used mvn install in the whole project and once more in avatica folder. Then, I imported as external jars calcite-example-csv, calcite-core, avatica , linq4j, avatica-metrics, avatica-standalone with all their sources and tests, and I get:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.calcite.config.CalciteConnectionProperty.valueClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
 at org.apache.calcite.avatica.ConnectionConfigImpl$PropEnv.getEnum(ConnectionConfigImpl.java:228) ...